# BIM360 Issues editor Forge Node JS App -trying to run on localhost 3000

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I am trying to work with the BIM 360 Issue Editor created by Petr and available on github https://github.com/petrbroz/bim360-issue-editor/tree/develop

I have added all the dependencies,etc. but seem to be stuck with the configuration.

I am testing on local host and I am getting invalid URI error, what would be the correct configuration variables for launch.json file for
"HOST_URL": "http://localhost:3000","SERVER_SESSION_SECRET","CLI_CONFIG_PASSWORD"

Also there is SENDGRID_API_KEY required, which throws an error on the console, I add the key from SendGrid in config.js, and the error goes away. Is it correct?

Please suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's more details about the env. variables:

- `HOST_URL` is just the host/port the app is listening on (for example, `http://localhost:3000`)

  - This value is used to built the *callback URL* for the 3-legged OAuth workflow; for example, if the host URL is `http://localhost:3000`, the callback URL will be `http://localhost:3000/auth/callback`
  - Note that the same *callback URL* must be configured for your Forge app on https://forge.autodesk.com/myapps
- `SERVER_SESSION_SECRET` is an arbitrary string that will be used to encrypt/decrypt browser cookies
- `CLI_CONFIG_PASSWORD` is only needed when you want to use the [command-line utility](https://github.com/petrbroz/bim360-issue-editor/tree/develop#command-line-utility) that's part of the sample code; in that case the configuration for the CLI utility will be zipped in a password-protected *.zip file using this env. variable as the password
- `SENDGRID_API_KEY` is also optional and only needed if you want the app to send email notifications to users who triggered the Excel export